# Deleting a WordPress theme without restoring its settings

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to remove a WordPress theme (Flatsam) but after deactivating and removing it, when I install it again, its settings and customizations come back. How can I delete it so that when I reinstall it after a while, it will be in the original state and the customizations I made before will not come back?

Please guide me to remove it in such a way that all its customizations will be removed as if it was never installed before!